# How to get row index of a gridview when autogenerated delete column button is fired?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have a gridview which has both autoGenerated delete as well as AutoGenerated select  buttons. I can get the current row of select button by gridView1.SelectedIndex but I can't get the same for the delete button. how to get it?

Comment: could you add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it by using the gridviews `rowDeleting` event

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDeleting
    (Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    TableCell cell = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
    if (cell.Text == "Beaver")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Message.Text = "You cannot delete customer Beaver.";
    }
    else
    {
        Message.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Note: This code was copied from, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx